# Using Moq to verify a method call on class in a collection

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm not sure if I'm using Moq the right way, so if anyone could help, I'd be grateful.

I want to test the call of Clone() method on object in a collection. The test looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void CloneTest()
{
    var mdFake = new Mock<MachineDecision>();
    var clonable = mdFake.As<ICloneable>();
    clonable.Setup(x => x.Clone()).Verifiable();

    var decision = new Decision()
    {
        MachineDecisions = new List<MachineDecision> { mdFake.Object }
    };

    var newDecision = (Decision) decision.Clone();

    clonable.Verify(x => x.Clone()); 
}
```

The test fails: `Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.Clone()` but I believe it should actually pass.

Used classes look as follows:

```
public class Decision : Entity<Guid>, ICloneable
{
    public Decision()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        MachineDecisions = new List<MachineDecision>();
    }

    public List<MachineDecision> MachineDecisions { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var obj = new Decision();
        if (this.MachineDecisions != null)
        {
            obj.MachineDecisions = MachineDecisions.Select(item => (MachineDecision) item.Clone()).ToList();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

public class MachineDecision : Entity<Guid>, ICloneable
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options available.

**First**, you can make an implementation of method `Clone()` virtual and your test will be 'Green'

```
public class MachineDecision : Entity<Guid>, ICloneable
{
    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Second**, you can invoke `Clone()` method from `ICloneable` interface: `(MachineDecision)(item as ICloneable).Clone()`; and your test will be 'Green' also.

```
    public class Decision : Entity<Guid>, ICloneable
    {
        public Decision()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            MachineDecisions = new List<MachineDecision>();
        }

        public List<MachineDecision> MachineDecisions { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            var obj = new Decision();
            if (this.MachineDecisions != null)
            {
                obj.MachineDecisions = MachineDecisions.Select(item =>
                {
                    return (MachineDecision)(item as ICloneable).Clone();
                }).ToList();
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

I realise that now it is not the best code but it is up to you how to refactor it further.

Comment: Thanks, both options indeed work. Now I get why the test I wrote didn't work. However it is quite interesting, that you cannot test this feature without making those small hacks in source code.

Comment: These two hacks solve the single one issue - **MOQ can't mock non-virtual members**. First hack makes method `Clone()` on entity of type `MachineDecision` virtual. Second hack invokes `Clone()` method from interface `ICloneable`, that can be mocked by MOQ.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
[Test]
public void CloneTest()
{
    // create the mock
    var mdFake = new Mock<MachineDecision>();

    var decision = new Decision
    {
        // setup (pass it to my collection)
        MachineDecisions = new List<MachineDecision> { mdFake.Object }
    };

    // call the method being tested (you need to make Clone() virtual)
    decision.Clone();

    // check for the side effects -> It was called once !
    mdFake.Verify(x => x.Clone(), Times.Once());
}
```

I hope this helps you.

**EDIT** - I'm sorry, as it was pointed in the comments - I forgot to mention, that what I'm suggesting requires you to make `Clone()` (in `MachineDecision`) - `virtual`, which might not be ideal in your case.

Comment: What I got using your code is: `System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Clone()`

Comment: You would need to make `Clone` `virtual` on `MachineDecision` with this solution

Comment: Yap, it works when `virtual`, all green. But I'm not sure if that's what I want. All in all, no class derives from `MachineDecision` so making this method `virtual` is kinda strange, isn't it? Anyway, the approach with `As<ICloneable>()` is no good?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
clonable.Expect(x => x.Clone()).Verifiable().Returns(null);
...
clonable.Verify();
```